# Is $TM$ a manifold with or without boundary when $M$ is a manifold with boundary?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

I am working on manifolds **with boundary**.

Assume $(E, \pi)$ is a vector bundle over a manifold with boundary $M$, for example $TM$ or $T^*M$. If $\phi : \pi^{-1}(\mathcal{U}) \to \mathcal{U} \times \mathbb{R}^m$ is a vector bundle chart of $E$ and $\varphi : \mathcal{U} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a chart (with boundary) of the manifold $M$, then we can (can we?) induce a manifold chart on $E$:
$$
\xi : \pi^{-1}(\mathcal{U}) \to \varphi(\mathcal{U}) \times \mathbb{R}^m : x \mapsto (\varphi(\pi(x)), t_{\pi(x)}^{-1}(x))
$$
where $t_p : \mathbb{R}^m \to \pi^{-1}(p)$ is the isomorphism between the vector space $\mathbb{R}^m$ and the fiber $\pi^{-1}(p)$ ($t_p(v) := \varphi^{-1}(p, v)$).

When $M$ is a manifold without boundary, we can then collect all the charts built in this way into an atlas and induce a manifold structure on $E$.

When $M$ is a manifold without boundary, is the construction above valid? Is $E$ equipped with this manifold structure a manifold with or without boundary?

In other words, if $M$ is a manifold with boundary, is $TM$ a manifold with or without boundary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the answer is yes, here there is my reasoning:
$$\mathbb{R}_+^m:= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^m\,|\,x_1 \geq 0\}$$
If $M$ is a manifold with boundary, for every boundary chart
$$\varphi : U \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}_+^m$$
the induced chart on $TM := \sqcup_{p \in M} T_pM$
$$\Phi : \pi^{-1}(U) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+^m \times \mathbb{R}^m$$
$$\Phi(X_p) = (\varphi(p),d\varphi^1|_p(X_p),..., d\varphi^m|_p(X_p) )$$
is a chart with boundary since $ \mathbb{R}_+^m \times \mathbb{R}^m = \mathbb{R}^{2m}_+$

Here $d\varphi^1|_p,..., d\varphi^m|_p$ is the dual basis of $T_p^*M$ and $\pi : TM \rightarrow M$ is the standard projection

Comment: Thank you! The same argument goes for a vector bundle in general I think. Do you know if $\partial TM$ is related to $TM|_{\partial M}$ ? Or if there is any way to characterise the boundary of vector bundle ?

Comment: I think we might just have $\partial (T M) = T(\partial M)$ and $\partial E = E|_{\partial M}$ in general.

Comment: @maxbo You are welcome! The same argument holds also for a general fiber bundle if the fiber $F$ is a manifold without boundary. I also think the same: $\partial E = E|_{\partial M}$